# Output column names instead of descriptions in SQL Assistant

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Using the 16.20 SQL Assistant, the switch in the picture does not affect the output in the Query Results. I always see column descriptions there. Is there any way to get the names in the grid instead?

[image]

Comment: Works as expected for me (SQLA 16.20.00.08) and the readme doesn't show any fixes regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected only for .NET (which is the preferred connection anyway), but you probably connect using ODBC which seems to override SQLA's setting. Check "Use Colum Names" in the data source "Options"

[image]

Comment: ODBC 15.10 driver, Assistant 16.20.0.7. Unchecked (and checked back) the "Use Column Names" - no such luck. Output (from a view) uses descriptions, while in the left tree panel - view columns are listed by name. Defect?

Comment: @access_granted: Checking the option works for me, can you try upgrading to a later ODBC version?